# D3 insert H3 tags Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, google-sheets

I'm trying to use D3 to generate some headers on an HTML document in a D3 project. I can get D3 to print the data to the console, but I'm not sure how to get it to show up on the HTML from the Google Sheet I'm using. Basically, I'm trying to call the specific value under a specific header and use that data value as the text for a header. The data prints to the console. I can manually generate the h3 tags, but I'm having difficult with binding my data and using enters.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-2" id="records">
  <strong>records obtained</strong>
  <div class="col-sm-2" id="records">
    <strong>records obtained</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
d3.csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12jMwpmqdbUUfcMHWg2GwGvu-d9BhaJOEsWjK1eoqHRc/pub?output=csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.rqt_count = d.rqt_count;
  });

  console.log(data[1]);

  d3.select("#records")
    .data()
    .enter()
    .append("h3")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.rqt_count;
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.selectAll('h3')` to associate new H3 elements with `#records`.

Also, you need to pass the `data` parameter to the `data` method:

```js
d3.csv("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12jMwpmqdbUUfcMHWg2GwGvu-d9BhaJOEsWjK1eoqHRc/pub?output=csv", 
       function(error, data) {
  d3.select("#records")
    .selectAll('h3')    //ADD THIS
      .data(data)       //CHANGE THIS
      .enter()
      .append("h3")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.rqt_count;
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2" id="records">
  <strong>records obtained</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. That was really simple. I love D3 because it does have a simple elegance to it, but the learning curve is steep. Thanks for the help. 

Follow-up question: How do I get the generated H3 content to appear before the existing <strong> element?

Comment: Change `.append("h3")` to `.insert("h3", "strong")`.  That will insert all the data before the <strong> element.